# Quadratic Forms and Associated Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

This might be a dumb question but when we write the matrix associated with a quadratic form, why does the matrix need to be symmetric in general? I'm asking because I'm thinking there isn't a unique matrix that is associated with a quadratic form unless you specifically state that the matrix has to be symmetric. If it has to be symmetric, why do some textbooks do not note that the matrix associated with the quadratic form needs to be symmetric?

Comment: From what I can see books from an applied perspective, where the field is always the real numbers and the topic is linear programming and quadratic programming, do not seem to require (or the people asking are not careful about stating) symmetry of the matrix. All the books I know on quadratic forms require a symmetric matrix; these would be from a number theory or algebra perspective.

Comment: Thank you! Yes the books that I've mentioned that do not specify that requirement are math for economics books so that might explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. The matrix used in a quadratic form does not need to be symmetric.  For instance, $x^T Q x$  is a quadratic form for any matrix $Q$.  The key part here is that we can always choose the matrix to be symmetric.  In particular,
for $Q' = (Q + Q^T)/2$,
we have

$x^T Q' x = (1/2) x^T Q x + (1/2) x^T Q^T x = x^T Q x$

Notice the equality here is because $x^T Q^T x = (x^T Q^T x)^T = x^T Q x$.

Therefore, we always assume that the matrix defining a quadratic form is symmetric.

Symmetry has many nice properties, so it is convenient to just start with the symmetric version.

Comment: I don't agree with that point of view: it is part/consequence of the definition that a quadratic form on a vector space (or a module) be associated to a *symmetric* bilinear form, even if it is conceivable that a quadratic form is associated to any matrix.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the definition of a quadratic form: it must derive from a bilinear symmetric form.

*In detail:* According to *Bourbaki, Algebra, ch.9*, a quadratic form on an $A$-module $E$ ($A$ commutative) is a map $Q\colon E\to A$ such that:

(i) $Q(\alpha x)=\alpha^2 Q(x)$ for all $\alpha\in A$ and $x\in E$

(ii) the map $\;\begin{aligned}[t]E \times E&\to A\\(x,y)&\mapsto \Phi(x,y)=P(x+y)-P(x)-P(y) \end{aligned}$
is a bilinear form (necessarily symmetric).